# How we can add the different different logo(images) header of drupal7 themes

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to add 3 different images in the header of the drupal-7. But i am able to add only one image can you tell me how we can add the different-different images in header of the drupal 7 themes without  effecting the code by using modules.

Comment: How about adding code in the theme's template.php file, is that allowed?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard, but you'll need to edit the page.tpl file of your chosen theme.

Editing the theme directly isn't recommended, as you'll lose the ability to upgrade without making the same changes on the upgraded version.

To learn how to create a sub theme see this page: http://drupal.org/node/225125

You need to create a directory called "mysubtheme" in your sites/all/themes or sites/mysite/themes folder. Then create a ".info" file called something like "mysubtheme.info" , which should contain the  name of your subtheme and a line like "base theme = whatever" to tell Drupal your theme is based on the original. Then copy page.tpl from the original theme, and edit to add your new images. That should be about it.

Hope that sets you on the right track.

James